# Mixed Taxable line item don't work

Tags: commerce

I have a cart with
1 x Food (non taxable)
1 x Electronic (taxable)

Currently both items are being taxed.

I need the GST and QST to only tax the taxable items.

What is the proper setup?

Comment: Please note that in some provinces an item could be taxable while in another it is not. There are province regulations. How do we apply them?